# Доступ к DOM при клике на кнопку в меню [Electron]

Tags: javascript, electron

Начал работать с электроном, попытался реализовать простой парсер по сайту. Идея: есть окно с сайтом в **main.js**

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const appMenu = require('./scripts/appMenu');

function createWindow() {
  appWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 800
  });
  appWindow.loadURL(`site`);
};

app.on('ready', () => {
   createWindow();
   const template = appMenu();
   const menu = electron.Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
   electron.Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
   app.quit();
});
```

Я создаю меню в файле **appMenu.js**:

```js
const { shell } = require('electron');
const dialog = require('electron').dialog;

module.exports = function appMenu() {
  return (
    [
      {
        label: 'File',
        submenu: [
          {
            label: 'Click me',
            click() {
                console.log(document)
             },
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  );
};
```

После **npm start** всё нормально рендерится и запускается, сайт прогружается. Но при клике на кнопку в меню возникает ошибка

[image: ошибка при клике по кнопке]

Как я понимаю, скрипт не видит DOM вообще. В теле клика у меня были объявлены также и глобальные переменные по типу **window.variable**, но скрипт жаловался даже на **window**, что он **undefined**

Как быть в такой ситуации? Вставлять сайт через **iframe** не хочется, с ним тоже морока при исполнении скрипта и морока с доступом к DOM элементам

Comment: _PvP или засцал..._ не работал с electron, но в тойже консоле браузера можно создать dom и с ним работать, может вам это поможет...

Comment: @RifmaMan к сожалению, это вообще не так:)